# How to remove an element in the name tag with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, I have an input tag like this:

```
<input class="" name="abcxyz[full_name]"/>
```

is there a way to use jquery to remove [full_name] from the name tag? I want it like this:

```
<input class="" name="abcxyz"/>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: your expected result is `<input class="" name="abcxyz"/>` ? and `[full_name]` must be removed?

Comment: yes, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes you can use `attr` and `replace` methods. check my answer

Comment: Why don't you just change the `<input>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try finding all the inputs with square brackets in their names and then removing the bracketed expressions via the [`.attr()` method](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2)

```js
const rx = /\[.+?\]/g // for finding and removing "[something]"

$("input[name*='[']")
  .filter((_, { name }) => rx.test(name))
  .attr("name", (_, name) => name.replace(rx, ""))
  
// This just shows the result
$("#out").text($("#inputs").html())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inputs">
  <input class="" name="abcxyz[full_name]"/>
  <input class="" name="abcxyz[full_name"/> <!-- no match -->
  <input class="" name="abcxyz[full_name][exta]"/> <!-- multiple matches -->
</div>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

The first selector finds all inputs with a `[` in the name. The filter then makes sure they only match `[something]`.

Comment: Your previous answer worked for me. Does this edit change anything?

Comment: @ThànhNamNguyễn it ensures you're not making changes to attributes that don't match.